# select_tag not passing param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My select_tag is suppose to auto post when a item is selected. It does but when I view the params in byebug I get a empty id in  the params instead of the selected id. Any idea what I am missing?

Before I get to much criticism I do know that a lot of this should be moved to the controller. :) I plan on moving it.

Params:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"jeuwTKfou9qOs8Gj5M4TKOs0Ed7kjeewuqqslKAXonw6T4MRafeurp0pOHFHgPoDV000ExqFnOQfF8S/8oV5/Q==", "id"=>"", "method"=>"post", "controller"=>"call_track", "action"=>"associate"}
```

Select tag in question:

```
select_tag :id, options_for_select(@project_job_selector),{:onchange => 'this.form.submit();', include_blank: true}
```

@project_job_selector:

```
def cache_jobs

    @root_jobs = Job.where(active:true,parent_id: nil).order("name")

    @project_job_selector = []

    @root_jobs.each {|job|
      if job.children.size > 0
        addmain=0
        job.children.each {|child|
          if (child.active?)
            addmain+=1
          end
        }
        name = (addmain >= 1 ? job.name + ' (Main Job)' : job.name )
      else
        name = job.name
      end
      @project_job_selector << [name, job.id]
      job.children.each {|subjob|
        @project_job_selector << ['  -- ' + subjob.name, subjob.id] if subjob.active?
      }
    }
    @project_job_selector
  end
```

Whole view:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#call_track_table').DataTable({
      responsive: true,
      scrollY: 400,
      paging: false
  });
  } );

  $(function() {
      $("#dialog").dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          modal: true,
          width: ($(window).width() - 300),
          height: ($(window).height() - 100),
          buttons: {
              'Cancel': function() {
                  $(this).dialog('close');
              }
          }
      });
      $(".dialogify").on("click", function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $("#dialog").html("");
          $("#dialog").dialog("option", "title", "Loading....").dialog("open");
          $("#dialog").load(this.href, function() {
              $(this).dialog("option", "title", 'Edit Task');
              $(this).find("title").remove();
          });
      });
  });
</script>
<h1>Live Call Track</h1>
<%= form_tag(controller: :call_track, action: :associate, method: :post) do %>
<table id="call_track_table" class="display responsive no-wrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%" >
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Start Time</th>
      <th>Duration</th>
      <th>Extension</th>
      <th>Direction</th>
      <th>Support Call</th>
      <th>Dialed Number</th>
      <th>Caller ID</th>
      <th>Project</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Start Time</th>
      <th>Duration</th>
      <th>Extension</th>
      <th>Direction</th>
      <th>Support Call</th>
      <th>Dialed Number</th>
      <th>Caller ID</th>
      <th>Project</th>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
  <tbody>

  <% @rs.each do |call| %>

    <% if User.where(:shoretel_ext => call['Extension']).present? then username = User.where(:shoretel_ext => call['Extension']).pluck(:nickname) else username = call['Extension'] end %>
    <% if User.where(:shoretel_ext => call['DialedNumber']).present? then dialednumber = User.where(:shoretel_ext => call['DialedNumber']).pluck(:nickname) else dialednumber = call['DialedNumber'] end %>
    <% if User.where(:shoretel_ext => call['CallerID']).present? then callerid = User.where(:shoretel_ext => call['CallerID']).pluck(:nickname) else callerid = call['CallerID'] end %>
      <%
        if username[0].length > 2 then
          username = username[0]
        end
        if dialednumber[0].length > 2 then
          dialednumber = dialednumber[0]
        end
        if callerid[0].length > 2 then
          callerid = callerid[0]
        end

      %>
      <%
      if call['CallType'] == 'Inbound' then
        phone = call['CallerID'].to_s
        phone.slice!(0,2)
        if Job.where("replace(replace(replace(replace(phone_main, ' ', ''), '-', ''),'(',''),')','') = '" + phone + "' OR replace(replace(replace(replace(phone_back, ' ', ''), '-', ''),'(',''),')','') = '" + phone + "' OR replace(replace(replace(replace(phone_cell, ' ', ''), '-', ''),'(',''),')','') = '" + phone + "' OR replace(replace(replace(replace(phone_emergency, ' ', ''), '-', ''),'(',''),')','') = '" + phone + "' OR replace(replace(replace(replace(phone_dsl, ' ', ''), '-', ''),'(',''),')','') = '" + phone + "'").present? then
          job = Job.where("replace(replace(replace(replace(phone_main, ' ', ''), '-', ''),'(',''),')','') = '" + phone + "' OR replace(replace(replace(replace(phone_back, ' ', ''), '-', ''),'(',''),')','') = '" + phone + "' OR replace(replace(replace(replace(phone_cell, ' ', ''), '-', ''),'(',''),')','') = '" + phone + "' OR replace(replace(replace(replace(phone_emergency, ' ', ''), '-', ''),'(',''),')','') = '" + phone + "' OR replace(replace(replace(replace(phone_dsl, ' ', ''), '-', ''),'(',''),')','') = '" + phone + "'").pluck(:id)
          job = job[0].to_i
        elsif ClientPhone.where(:phone => phone)
          job = ClientPhone.where(:phone => phone).pluck(:client_id)
          job = job[0].to_i
        else
          job = 0
        end

        if job > 0 then
          job_name = Job.find_by_id(job)
          job_name = job_name.name
        end
      end
      if call['CallType'] == 'Outbound' then
        phone = call['DialedNumber'].to_s
        phone.slice!(0,2)
        if Job.where("replace(replace(replace(replace(phone_main, ' ', ''), '-', ''),'(',''),')','') = '" + phone + "' OR replace(replace(replace(replace(phone_back, ' ', ''), '-', ''),'(',''),')','') = '" + phone + "' OR replace(replace(replace(replace(phone_cell, ' ', ''), '-', ''),'(',''),')','') = '" + phone + "' OR replace(replace(replace(replace(phone_emergency, ' ', ''), '-', ''),'(',''),')','') = '" + phone + "' OR replace(replace(replace(replace(phone_dsl, ' ', ''), '-', ''),'(',''),')','') = '" + phone + "'").present? then
          job = Job.where("replace(replace(replace(replace(phone_main, ' ', ''), '-', ''),'(',''),')','') = '" + phone + "' OR replace(replace(replace(replace(phone_back, ' ', ''), '-', ''),'(',''),')','') = '" + phone + "' OR replace(replace(replace(replace(phone_cell, ' ', ''), '-', ''),'(',''),')','') = '" + phone + "' OR replace(replace(replace(replace(phone_emergency, ' ', ''), '-', ''),'(',''),')','') = '" + phone + "' OR replace(replace(replace(replace(phone_dsl, ' ', ''), '-', ''),'(',''),')','') = '" + phone + "'").pluck(:id)
          job = job[0].to_i
        elsif ClientPhone.where(:phone => phone)
          job = ClientPhone.where(:phone => phone).pluck(:client_id)
          job = job[0].to_i
        else
          job = 0
        end

        if job > 0 then
          job_name = Job.find_by_id(job)
          job_name = job_name.name
        end
      end
      if call['CallType'] == 'ExtToExt' then
        job = -1
      end
  %>
      <% if call['Extension'].to_i != 4010 then %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to call['StartTime'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), {:controller => :call_track, :action => :call_segments, :call_id => call['ID'] }, class: 'dialogify' %></td>
    <td><%= call['StartTime'].strftime('%I:%M %p')  %></td>
    <td><%= TimeDifference.between(call['StartTime'], call['EndTime']).in_minutes %> Minutes</td>
    <td><%= username %></td>
    <td><%= call['CallType'] %></td>
    <td><%= if call['WorkgroupCall'] == 1 then 'True' else 'False' end %></td>
    <td><%= dialednumber  %></td>
    <td><%= callerid %></td>
    <td><%= if job == 0 then select_tag :id, options_for_select(@project_job_selector),{:onchange => 'this.form.submit();', include_blank: true} elsif job == -1 then '' else job_name.to_s end %></td>
  </tr>
  <%end%>
  <%end%>
  </tbody>
</table>
    <%end%>
<div id="dialog"></div>
<br>
<br>
<div id="historical_form">

</div>
```

this is Rails 4

Comment: what values you have in `@project_job_selector`? . Also try, 
`select_tag "id", options_for_select(@project_job_selector),{:onchange => 'this.form.submit();', include_blank: true}`

Comment: I added the code for the @project_job_selector above. It is in the ApplicationController and used in multiple places. I tried adding quotes around id and it makes no difference

Comment: In your view do `<%= @project_job_selector %>` and check if there is some data in it?

Comment: I know there is data in it, The drop down shows roughly 500 options. it just wont pass the id back in the param when selected. going to try that though just to see what it does, ill post back

Comment: so many results that it crashes the browser, about 500 options in the selector and about 200 rows in the table. the select is ["Job Name", 121]

Comment: try adding method outside the hash, `<%= form_tag({controller: "call_track", action: "associate"}, method: "post") do %>`

Comment: id param still empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133944/discussion-between-sravan-and-devon-quick).

Comment: we can continue in chat today. I fell asleep last night

Comment: so, the answer was solved. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

putting my form_tag inside the table cell fixed it.

```
<tr>
    <td><%= link_to call['StartTime'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), {:controller => :call_track, :action => :call_segments, :call_id => call['ID'] }, class: 'dialogify' %></td>
    <td><%= call['StartTime'].strftime('%I:%M %p')  %></td>
    <td><%= TimeDifference.between(call['StartTime'], call['EndTime']).in_minutes %> Minutes</td>
    <td><%= username %></td>
    <td><%= call['CallType'] %></td>
    <td><%= if call['WorkgroupCall'] == 1 then 'True' else 'False' end %></td>
    <td><%= dialednumber  %></td>
    <td><%= callerid %></td>
    <td><%= form_tag({controller: "call_track", action: "associate"}, method: "post") do %><%= if job == 0 then select_tag(:job_id,options_for_select(@jobs),{include_blank: true,:onchange => 'this.form.submit();'})  elsif job == -1 then '' else job_name.to_s end %><%end%></td>
  </tr>
```